# BackDropFilter doesn't run (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm programming a simple validation screen, and I decided to use BackDropFilter to use some blur, but it doesn't work, it says that ImageFilter isn't defined.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../constants.dart';

class ValidationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              kMap,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
            BackdropFilter(
              filter: prefix0.ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
              child: Container(color: kValidationBG),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add also this package

`import 'dart:ui';`

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering an issue where `ImageFilter` is not defined when trying to use `BackdropFilter` for blur effect in Flutter, you may need to import ImageFilter from the dart:ui library.

Make sure to add this import statement at the top of your Dart file. After importing, you can use ui.ImageFilter.blur to apply the blur effect.

Example usage:

```js
import 'dart:ui' as ui show ImageFilter;

BackdropFilter(
  filter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
  child: YourContentWidget(),
)
```

Adjust the values of sigmaX and sigmaY based on the level of blur you want to achieve. If you encounter any other issues or have further questions, feel free to ask!